# clearing ajax success message upon modal close

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using w3.css and its modal functionality and I am trying to clear the message generated after a successful ajax call once the window is closed. However, when I close the window (by clicking outside the modal window), then opening the modal again, the text from the previous ajax call still is on the screen. Here is the code I have in place for the closing of the modal:

```
var modal_id = document.getElementById('edit-photo-modal');

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal_id) {
        $('#edit-photo-form').find('input:text, select').val('');
        $('.w3-row').find('.w3-twothird w3-text-white').html("");
        $('.w3-row').find('.w3-threequarter w3-text-white').html("");
        modal_id.style.display = 'none';
    }
};
```

the two success messages classes can either be `.w3-twothird w3-text-white` or `.w3-threequarter w3-text-white`.

This is a screenshot of a successful edit.

[image]

but once I close the modal then reopen it, the success text remains in the modal window. I would like to have it cleared once the modal window loses focus and not have to reload the page in order for it to do so.

If it helps, here is the relevant ajax to this:

```
$('#save-bw-photo').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
        url: "/members/profile/handle-photo-edit",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            bw_image: 1,
            album_name: $('#album-name option:selected').val(),
            photo: /[^/]*$/.exec($('#selected-photo img').attr('src'))[0],
            colorspace: $('#colorspace option:selected').val(),
            channel: $('#channel option:selected').val()
        }
    }).done(function(msg) {
        $('#bw-message').attr('style', 'display: initial;');
        $('#bw-msg').html(msg.success_bw);
    }).fail(function(msg) {
        $('#bw-message').attr('style', 'display: initial;');
        $('#bw-msg').html(msg.fail_bw);
    });
});
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks!

(If the information or question I provided/asked is unclear, please let me know and I will try to clarify it as best as I can)

Comment: Use .clear() on the elemnts you bind data on.

Comment: in the window.onclick function?

Comment: `#bw-msg` is the container of the success message?

Comment: for that particular one yes but it is different for each option. here is the format for the bw message `<div class="w3-row" style="display: none;" id="bw-message">
      <p class="w3-threequarter w3-text-white" id="bw-msg"></p>
     </div>`

it's the same for the others, just a different id.

Comment: @user2101411 why is that there's no [dot] on  `w3-text-white` class? Isn't it should be like 
 $('.w3-row').find('.w3-twothird.w3-text-white').html("");
        $('.w3-row').find('.w3-threequarter.w3-text-white').html("");

Comment: hm, I didn't think of that, I thought jquery would use both

Comment: @leonardeveloper that fixed it, thanks!

Comment: @user2101411 perhaps you'll consider my answer to your question and I suggest you apply it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
    var modal_id = document.getElementById('edit-photo-modal');

    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal_id) {
        $('#edit-photo-form').find('input:text, select').val('');
        $('.w3-row').find('.w3-twothird w3-text-white').html("");
        $('.w3-row').find('.w3-threequarter w3-text-white').html("");
        modal_id.style.display = 'none';
    }
   };
```

Try

```
  $(document).on('#edit-photo-modal','click',function(){
    $('#edit-photo-form').find('input:text, select').val('');
    $('.w3-row').find('.w3-text-white').html("");
    $(this).hide();
  });
```

Comment: it's not making the modal disappear.

Comment: `var modal_id = document.getElementById('edit-photo-modal');` Is this the modal ID?

Comment: @user2101411 You can do `$('#modal id here').hide();`

Comment: `var modal_id = document.getElementById('edit-photo-modal');
 
  window.onclick = function(event) {
   if (event.target == modal_id) {
    $('#edit-photo-form').find('input:text, select').val("");
    $('.w3-row').find('.w3-text-white').html("");
    modal_id.style.display = 'none';
   }
  };` this works, so I'll just use this, thanks though